# How to pass dynamic array on different pages in php?

Tags: php

i need to pass array from one page to other pages through button click .actually i fetch each column of database in an array nw i want to pass that array to different pages. i used the session varaible but it is not workng.

coding og page2.php in which theses dynamic arrays are get

```
<?php


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $data_t1 = $_POST['t1'];


    foreach ($data_t1 as $key => $value) {

        $value ;
       $_POST['t2'][$key];
    $_POST['a1'][$key];
      $_POST['username'][$key];
  }
      $data_t2 = $_POST['t2'];
      $data_t3=$_POST['a1'];
      $data_t4=$_POST['username'];
}
```

now i put theses array in databse n fetch them i need to pass these fetch array into next page

```
<?php
  //database connection
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ems",'root','');
//query
$sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (c0,c1, c2, c3, c4,) VALUES ('',:c1, :c2, :c3, :c4,)
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
foreach ($data_t1 as $i => $value) {
    $stmt->execute(array(
       ':c1'=>$data_t1[$i],
       ':c2'=>$data_t2[$i],
       ':c3'=>$data_t3[$i],
       ':c4'=>$data_t4[$i],
    <?php
    include('config.php');
    $sa="select * from table1 where timestamp=now()";
    $result=mysql_query($sa) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    { 
         $row['c1'];
       $row['c2'];
         $row['c3'];
         $row['c4'];
    $m[]=round(($row['c1']/$row['c4']);
    $n[]=round(($row['c2']/$row['c4']),2);
    $o[]=round(($row['c3']/$row['c4']),2);
    $row_count++;

}
```

here i call the the fecth array for displayng

```
<?php 
    session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] =$r;
$_SESSION['name1'] = $r1;
$_SESSION['name2'] = $r2;
    for($i=0;$i<$row_count;$i++) 
    { // do the exploding, the imploding, the row echoing for each row// 
?>

<?php
    echo "<table border='1' align='center'>
    <tr>
    <th>Inputs</th>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
    </tr>";
    echo "Meas1".($i+1);
      echo "<tr>";

         $f=implode($m,',');
         $r=explode(',',$f);

         $f1=implode($n,',');
         $r1=explode(',',$f1);

         $f2=implode($o,',');
         $r2=explode(',',$f2);
display of data

    echo "<td>".$r[$i]. "</td>";
    echo "<td>".$r1[$i]. "</td>";
    echo "<td>".$r2[$i]. "</td>";

}
```

the above all codng on page2.php when i acess these `r[],r1[],r2[]`on `next page` i.e. `page3.php` it disply me empty array

```
    page3.php


 <?php
session_start();
$r= $_SESSION['name'];
echo $r;
var_dump($r);
print_r($r);
$r1= $_SESSION['name1'];
echo $r1;
print_r($r1);

$r2= $_SESSION['name2'];
echo $r2;
print_r($r2);

?>
```

plz help for ths

Comment: I am not certainly reading this, but as far as the question goes, use super global var like `$_SESSION` to pass values to different pages

Comment: @Mr.Alien uh...he does...

Comment: where are your `session_start()` and `$_SESSION usages`? Read the manual! http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php, and look at the examples section in the manual if you are lazy. ( **EDIT** Uhm. did you just edit your question within 5 minutes!? because I didn't see $_SESSION before I wrote this.)

Comment: @imulsion I didn't read anything... this is so big

Comment: You are missing some quotes. Don't know if that's a typo or is in your code, but still...

Comment: this is the work iam actually doing i just want the array m[],n[],o[] to pass to page3.php plz help me ppl

Comment: @user2444690 welcome to SO! It's a good idea to use proper english here rather than text speak.

Comment: And please have a look at www.sscce.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use sessions, you are going to have to put `session_start()` in there at the beginning of every page:

```
<?php
session_start();
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $de; $i++) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>T</td>
        <td>
        //rest of enormous amount of code...
```

Put that method at the start of every page, immediately after `<?php`

Comment: @user2444690 In that case, start a new file with this code: <?php session_start(); ?> Save it, then add this where session_start() was in your other files: require_once("newfile.php");

Comment: in page3.php or page2.php ? i editedd my question kindly check ths

Comment: @user2444690 add require_once("newfile.php"); to all of your other files

Comment: @user2444690 I'm sorry, I don't know why that's happening :(

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize your array and pass it in url. the links below explains [Saving arrays](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/5/11/0)
and [php serialze](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php), use get method to get the array and unserialize.

**Page with form/button**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    //this is a sample array
    $samplearray = array(
                        't1' => 'this is t1',
                        't2' => 'this is t2',
                        'a1' => 'this is a1',
                        'username' =>'this is username'
                    );
    $str = serialize($samplearray);
    $strenc = urlencode($str);  
    $_SESSION['array'] = $samplearray;
?>
<form action="page2.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="array" value="<?php echo $strenc; ?>"/>
<input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" />
</form>
```

**page2.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['btnsubmit'])) {
$array = $_POST['array'];
$arr = unserialize(urldecode($array));


echo "Unserialized array";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<br/><br/>SESSION array";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION['array']);
echo "</pre>";
}
?>
```

Remember you have to use `session_start()` in all the pages. I have used bot session and array serialize in this example.

Hope this helps you.

Email me if you require additional help.

kumar_av@usp.ac.fj

Comment: sir help me reagrdng my question

Comment: So you want to pass array from one page to another with just a button click. You can use sessions or you can also serialize array. the easiest one id sessions. I have edited my answer, please see above.